# In Angular, how to get a form in $scope in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Having these two files:

HTML:

```
<form name="registrationForm" ng-submit="registerUser()">
   ...
</form>
```

JS (inside the Angular controller):

```
$scope.registrationForm.confirmPassword.$setValidity("PasswordsMatch", $scope.validation.doPasswordsMatch);
```

I get the error that `Cannot read property 'confirmPassword' of undefined`

This leads me to believe that I have no access to the form `registrationForm` in the controller. Based on this (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) I imagined that I should.

Other solutions that I've seen include passing the form to the controller when the form is submitted, but what I need to do (set custom validation) needs to happen way before that.

Other solution mentioned adding the controller to the form via `ng-controller` but that changed nothing.

EDIT: 
From the website above, is there a reason why in here (https://plnkr.co/edit/ZT0G6ajdbescT72qLKSU?p=preview) $scope.myForm can be accessed, but only inside of the `$scope.setEmpty` function?

Comment: `<form form="registrationForm" ng-submit="registerUser()">` should be `<form name="registrationForm" ng-submit="registerUser()">`, name is valid attribute for form tag

Comment: Sorry, that was originally `name` instead of `form`. Just fixed it the question.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the controller itself instead of the `$scope` provider for this. This was one of the first issues I came across when working with angularjs

In your controller:

```
function MyController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.registrationForm.confirmPassword.$setValidity("PasswordsMatch", $scope.validation.doPasswordsMatch);
}
```

In your form:

```
<form name="vm.registrationForm" ng-submit="registerUser()">
   ...
</form>
```

The only gotcha is that you need to specify the `controllerAs` property in your route or ngInclude:

```
ng-include="templates/my-template.html" ng-controller="MyController as vm"
```

or

```
when('/my-route', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/my-template.html',
  controller: 'MyController as vm'
 })
```

Comment: Is there a reason why we have to use the variable `vm`? can we just do `this.registrationForm...`?

Comment: Additionally, I did the steps in your snippets #1, #2, and #4 (I set the controller in the router) but I still get the same error.

Comment: You must make sure you are using the `controllerAs` when referencing your template or it will not work. You might be able to use `this` but it's bad practice because `this` is contextual and changes meaning depending on where it is used

Comment: You don't have to use `vm` but it is the preferred name. Check out this style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: The line where I set the controller is `... controller: 'RegistrationController as vm'...` Is that not how you set it controllerAs?

Comment: Yes, that's determines how the controller is referenced in the template. If you use `as vm` then in your template you must reference the controller with that exact name: `name="vm.registrationForm"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122231/discussion-between-sammy-i-and-joelcdoyle).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a name attribute to form element.

```
<form name="registrationForm" ng-submit="registerUser()">
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: It is originally `name`, must have changed it by accident when writing the question. Just fixed it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

this form must rely on a controller indeed. please take a look at the example:

```js
angular.module("fooApp",[]);

angular.module("fooApp")
  .controller("formctl",function(){
    this.user={};
    this.dosave=function(){
      if(this.user.pwd == this.user.confpwd)
        alert(this.user.username+" logged");
      else
        alert("pwd does not match");
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fooApp">
  <h1>sample</h1>
  <div ng-controller="formctl as ctl">
    <form ng-submit="ctl.dosave()">
      <label>username</label><br/>
      <input ng-model="ctl.user.username" required/><br/>
      <label>password</label><br/>
      <input ng-model="ctl.user.pwd" type="password" required/><br/>
      <label>confirm password</label><br/>
      <input ng-model="ctl.user.confpwd" type="password"/><br/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pass the form into the submit function to pass the entire form into the controller.  Use the form name.

```
<form name="registrationForm" ng-submit="registerUser(registrationForm)">
...
</form>
```

The other option would be to pass the inputs directly in as params

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate >
  some input: <input type="text" name="sometext" ng-model="myInput">
  <input type="submit" ng-click="doAction(myInput)">
</form>
```

Quick Plunk
https://plnkr.co/edit/s0Al2LTHkvUPoLYNzTpm?p=info

If you're just after the value of the inputs, it's easier to test if you have explicit parameters that you expect on the method instead of dumping in the entire form.

Comment: That is what I am doing right now, but I want to implement real time validation, instead of validation that only happens when the user submits the form.

Comment: @SammyI. See if this works for you.  There's even a plunk included.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/10/13/confirm-password-validation-in-angularjs.aspx