# How does one set custom validation on an Angular form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope

I am trying to set custom validation on an input field in an Angular app. The validation cannot be set to a pattern, since it is based on the content of another field (e.i. Passwords must match)

A way to do validation in this case is to check for the fields on form input. However, I want to be able to check for the validity in real time, and be able to use CSS classes such as `.ng-dirty` and `.ng-valid`, which come when Angular takes care of validation.

I tried to use `$scope.formName.inputName.$setValidity(...)`, but I am running into issues on that end (StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234656/in-angular-how-to-get-a-form-in-scope-in-controller/39235116)).

Is there another way in AngularJS to set custom validation?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned if you check 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation
You'll see you can use **directives** to create your own custom validations, in the example provided the validation is done whenever you input a character.

If you use your browser to inspect the example (username input field) you'll see the classes (ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-valid ng-valid-username) being changed on the fly.

If you had a form these classes would be taken into account to change the form.$valid property to true or false. By default if form.$valid is false then you can't submit it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesnt answer to your question but I found a couple of directives that can do that for you:

https://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/angularjs-directive-to-check-that-passwords-match/

https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-validation-match

Try it out to see if its what you need.